# Select in Bootstrap modal window doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make a modal window, in which i choose an option from form select and pass it for further functionallity.
The problem is, that when the select list drops down, i can't change the selected option. This problem occures only in Firefox. In Chrome it seems working well.

Below is the code, that i used in my application. I don't have any additional styles or scripts, besides thoose from Bootstrap.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch
</button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" data-backdrop="static">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div>
                    <select class="form-control" >
                      <option selected>1</option>
                      <option>2</option>
                      <option>3</option>
                      <option>4</option>
                      <option>5</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id='generate'>Generate</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Is there extra styling that you've added to this that you didn't include in your code? I was able to get it to work on Firefox in a jsfiddle

Comment: Ya its working for me as well....

Comment: @alyssums no, i there is no additional style included.

It's preety strange, because it turns out, that it occasionally works even at my computer. I will try to find in which cases it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

I removed the attribute `tabindex="-1"` (or sets to 0) of the modal, and I added javascript:

```
$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = $.noop;
```

https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/4091#issuecomment-172633858 ->

**Solution**: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/600#issuecomment-102857595