# Ngx bootstrap and input file element

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-modal, angular8, ngx-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal (ngx bootstrap) and inside that i have a file input control(input type=file).

I open the modal from another component using

```
modalService.show(componentName);
```

Once, the modal is opened

When i a select a file from browse button and double click it, the modal closes, whereas, when i select a file and click open button (instead of directly double clicking), the file is selected and modal doesn't close. This issue is seen in firefox, but not in edge or chrome.

```
<div class="modal-body">
<input type="file" id="fileElement"/>
</div>
<div> class="modal-footer">
<button (click)="saveMethod()">Save</button>
</div>
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: take a look at this hopethis help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138690/select-in-bootstrap-modal-window-doesnt-work-in-firefox

Comment: Sorry, that link is different

Comment: Anyone facing this issue? pls. share it, if you have resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I detected the same behaviour in my app today. This only happens in firefox and not edge (haha) or chrome.
This happens when double clicking to select a file in a ngx-bootstrap modal. Now it is important to note that it only happens in a specific case. I will try to explain as best i can but english isn't my first language.

Imagine there are 3 layers in your website. The first layer is your web page. the second layer is your opened modal. the third layer is your file selection popup.

The problem occurs when you double click to select a file, and the place you click in the file selection popup (layer 3) is above the main web page (layer 1).

If you double click to select your file (layer 3) above your modal (layer 2) there will be no problem.

This also only happens when you have not activated the backdrop: 'static' option. This option prevent the modal closing when clicking outside the modal.
To me this seems like a bug, whether caused by firefox or the ngx-bootstrap library i don't know but it's annoying.
The best solution would be a way to prevent the double click event to propagate but i couldn't make it happen. The only solution i found was to use the backdrop option but i don't like it either. In an angular app you can add [config]="{ backdrop: 'static' }" on your modal component.